# Magento 1.9.3 Connect Manager not working

Tags: magento-connect, magento1.9.3

Everytime I try to install an extention via Connect Manager, and right after I click on the Install button, it ask me for the login again. But then the login is not working anymore. What happened here?

See screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to change permission of

directory /downloader/ set to **755**

and file /downloader/index.php set to **644**.